# How to find middle of the string, next to space and dot in MongoDB

Tags: regex, mongodb, aggregate

```
 [
    {
        "Name": "Dr.Soma",
        "Email": "drsoma@gmail.com",
        "MobNo": 111111111
    }, 
   {
        "Name": "Bootha Ganesh",
        "Email": "boothaganesg@gmail.com",
        "MobNo": 222222222
    }, 
   {
        "Name": "Steven",
        "Email": "steven@gmail.com",
        "MobNo": 333333333
    },
    {
            "Name": "Dr.Anbarasi",
            "Email": "anbarasi@gmail.com",
            "MobNo": 4444444444
     }
     ]
```

I try this to using find regex

```
db.details.find({Name:{$regex:/steven/i}})
```

output:

```
   {
      "Name": "Steven",
      "Email": "steven@gmail.com",
      "MobNo": 333333333
    }
```

**How to find data Name dot(.) after Soma & Space after Ganesh** 
**Excepted Output**
If I find Name Ganesh,I need

```
{
            "Name": "Bootha Ganesh",
            "Email": "boothaganesg@gmail.com",
            "MobNo": 222222222
  }
```

If I find Name small s or capital S ,I need

```
{
        "Name": "Dr.Soma",
        "Email": "drsoma@gmail.com",
        "MobNo": 111111111
 }
```

No Need Name Dr.Anbarasi data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({"Name": {'$regex': /\bsoma[a-zA-Z0-9]*/gi}})
```

**\b** assert position at **a word boundary**: (^\w | \w$ | \W\w|\w\W)
soma-for searching value
**[a-zA-Z0-9]**-word characters
*-to entire string

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.find({ Name: { $regex: "Soma" } })
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gvsa5m0Ezp0)

---

```
db.collection.find({ Name: { $regex: ".Soma" } })
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wYoEf5gDKWB)

---

```
db.collection.find({ Name: { $regex: " Ganesh" } })
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nUQOiVZbDnW)

Comment: If i find name small s . i found 2 datas https://mongoplayground.net/p/pPDcboduzq5, I need only Soma data